# how to open html file automatically using webbrowser package in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-webbrowser

I have a python script that use pandas and create dataframe from csv file and i want to display the dataframe information using **pandas-profiling package** and show the report in the browser once  the user run the function .

But the system does not open the browser and display this error:

```
ValueError: startfile: filepath too long for Windows
```

## code:

```
def displayDfInfo(self,df):
        profile = pp.ProfileReport(df)
        html_profile = profile.to_html()
        webbrowser.open(html_profile,new=1)
```

where is the error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify it to this:

```
import webbrowser
html = "myhtml.html"
webbrowser.open(html)
```